# How to have a vertex shader with no vertex input attributes?

Tags: vulkan

I want to call a shader for vertices but the vertices will not be coming from the vertex input stream, they will be 'pulled' from a storage buffer. How can I make it so that nothing is read in from a vertex stream? Do I still have to bind a vertex buffer? If so, do I have to use a dummy? What do you specify for the vertex description when you specify:

```
description.binding;
description.stride;
description.inputRate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply pass an empty `VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo` at pipeline creation time, e.g.:

```cpp
VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineCI{};
...
VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo emptyVertexInputState{};
emptyVertexInputState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
pipelineCI.pVertexInputState = &emptyVertexInputState;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no vertex attributes, so your `VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo::vertexAttributeDescriptionCount` is zero. You are not reading anything from vertex input bindings, so `vertexBindingDescriptionCount` is zero.

You have no vertex descriptions, so you don't specify anything for those settings. You are not reading from vertex buffers, so you don't bind any.